# Cached data in onPause() of fragment is null when comes back to the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment, it contains a `MapView` in layout (but it is not related with the question I am going to ask, but keep it in mind please.):

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

   // I have a variable used to cache data in onPause()
   private MyData mData;

   @BindView(R.id.map)
   MapView mMapView;

   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       // I initiate my data in onCreate()
       mData = new MyData();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, container, false);
       if (mMapView != null) {
            // initiate map view
            mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // in onPause() I cache the data I got from another instance
        mData = someInstance.getHoldData();
    }

    /*map view callback! Here, I check the value of mData, when comes back to this fragment, it always get called*/
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        // I use data here, when comes back to this fragment, this is always called.
       // PROBLEM: sometimes mData is null, why?
       checkCachedData(mData);
    }
}
```

So, here is what I have above:

1. I initate `mData` in `onCreate()` callback of MyFragment, which only called once.
2. I prepare the map view in `onCreateView(...)` which always called when comes back to this fragment.
3. I cache the data in onPause()

`onCreate()` of `MyFragment` **is called first time launch the fragment.**

**PROBLEM:** When I go to another fragment and comes back to `MyFragment`, the `onCreate()` is **not** called which means in memory there is still the previous instance of MyFragment.  But then, **sometimes** `mData` is **null** in `onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)` callback when comes back to this fragment. Why? I don't understand it. Why `mData` could be null & onCreate() is not called?

**==== I switch to another fragment by : ===**

```
getTransaction().addToBackStack(myStack).replace(containerId, nextFragment, TAG).commit();
```

Comment: are you sure oncreate isnt callled? how are you switching fragments? when i call 
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  ft.add(CONTENT_VIEW_ID, newFragment).commit();

then oncreate is called

Comment: I mean onCreate is not called when comes back from another fragment. It is called in the first place when `MyFragment` is first time launched.

Comment: i know i meant how are you switching fragments back and forth?

Comment: `getTransaction().addToBackStack(myStack).replace(containerId, nextFragment, TAG).commit();`

Comment: don't store cached data in fragments, store it in a class that is responsible for cached data

Comment: @TimCastelijns could you please explain a bit about the problem store cached data in fragment? I try to understand why in my case the `mData` sometimes null in the place where I am checking, though your answer is what I plan to do as well.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that when you say you have an other fragment where you go to, you mean you are navigating, for example, using a navigation drawer. 
When your fragment is replaced by an other fragment, the first fragment goes on pause. This means the onPause callback is called. When the fragment comes back as the foreground fragment, it is resumed, so the onResume callback is called. To solve your issue, you should:

- cache the data in onPause;
- restore it in onResume.

Comment: But the problem is that I have to show the cached data on google map, which means I have to wait until the map ready callback `onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) ` is called. That's why the `mData` is checked in that google map callback.

Comment: Besides, your answer still doesn't explain why the `mData` is null sometimes.

Comment: Can you please provide the code for this?

    someInstance.getHoldData();

Comment: It is just a instance hold data, data there is never null, I am sure, & checked.

Comment: but I don't see a point of doing this, because the map is not ready in onResume(), if I do anything on Map with the mData, it will be NPE.

Comment: that's exactly the point, @Leem! If mData became null before onMapReady gets called, you'll experience an exception. To preved this, you can use onResume to restore the value of mData. You should use onPause to read the value of your mData and store it somewhere (not in the mData of your Fragment, becase, as per doc, it is not assured its value will be hold!), then, in the onResume, you'll have to restore the saved value

Comment: OK, I will try that soon. Thanks for the suggestion, I understand now.